# PHP CodeIgniter Batch Insert Not Accepting My Array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm unable to get the following code to work, and it has something to do with the forming of the array. The array is actually build after a foreach() loop runs a few times, then I want to batch insert, but it comes up malformed. Why?

```
    foreach ($results as $r) {
$insert_array = array(
                            'ListingRid' => $r['ListingRid'],
                            'StreetNumber' => $r['StreetNumber'],
                            'StreetName' => $r['StreetName'],
                            'City' => $r['City'],
                            'State' => $r['State'],
                            'ZipCode' => $r['ZipCode'],
                            'PropertyType' => $r['PropertyType'],
                            'Bedrooms' => $r['Bedrooms'],
                            'Bathrooms' => $r['Bathrooms'],
                            'YearBuilt' => (2011 - $r['Age']),
                            'Status' => $r['Status'],
                            'PictureCount' => $r['PictureCount'],
                            'SchoolDistrict' => $r['SchoolDistrict'],
                            'ListedSince' => $r['EntryDate'],
                            'MarketingRemarks' => $r['MarketingRemarks'],
                            'PhotoUrl' => (!empty($photo_url) ? $photo_url : 'DEFAULT'),
                            'ListingAgentFirstName' => $r['ListingAgentFirstName'],
                            'ListingAgentLastName' => $r['ListingAgentLastName'],
                            'ContactPhoneAreaCode1' => (!empty($a['ContactPhoneAreaCode1']) ? $a['ContactPhoneAreaCode1'] : 'DEFAULT'),
                            'ContactPhoneNumber1' => (!empty($a['ContactPhoneNumber1']) ? $a['ContactPhoneNumber1'] : 'DEFAULT'),
                            'ListingOfficeName' => (!empty($r['ListingOfficeName']) ? $r['ListingOfficeName'] : 'DEFAULT'),
                            'OfficePhoneComplete' => (!empty($o['OfficePhoneComplete']) ? $o['OfficePhoneComplete'] : 'DEFAULT'),
                            'last_updated' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                        );

                        $insert[] = $insert_array;

}

                        $this->db->insert_batch('listings', $insert);
```

Here's the errors:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: array_keys() [function.array-keys]: The first argument should
>   be an array
>
> Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php
>
> Line Number: 1148
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
>
> Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php
>
> Line Number: 1149

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reduced your code to the bare minimum and it seems to work.

```
        $i = 0;
        while ($i <= 10) {

            $insert_array = array(
                                        'code' => 'asd'
            );

            $insert[] = $insert_array;
            $i++;
        }


        $this->db->insert_batch('group', $insert);
```

You should check the elements of the array, comment them all and de-comment them one by one until you got the culprit.

Comment: I think it may be because my array is too large. It's working, but can insert batch do 1000+ records at a time?

Comment: I don't think it would be too many records, as you would get a different error. This part of your code looks suspicious:
`(!empty($a['ContactPhoneAreaCode1']) ? $a['ContactPhoneAreaCode1'] : 'DEFAULT')`.  I think this code returns a boolean because you have it wrapped in parentheses.  Although i don't see this as the culprit, I agree with @HerrKaleun and that you might check the elements of the array, as all of the other code looks correct (based on CIs docs).

Comment: I agree with swatkins too, you should check every array one by one because the 'basic edition' of your code works.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to wrap your array in a second array.  You're supposed to provide an array of row arrays.

```
$insert_array = array(array(...));
```

Comment: How can I create such an array from a normal array like
 Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [track_id] => 
            [camp_id] => 1
            [email_title] => sample
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [track_id] => 
            [camp_id] => 1
            [email_date] => 2013-07-02
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [track_id] => 
            [camp_id] => 1
            [email_template] => 2
        )