# error using codeigniter insert_batch

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working with insert_batch for so long and I can't figure how it works so, I need some guidance for this error.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given

Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php

Line Number: 1109
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php

Line Number: 1110
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php

Line Number: 1140
A Database Error Occurred

You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\squline_beta\dashboard\system\database\DB_active_rec.php

Line Number: 1054
```

I'm using CI 2 and that error comes up because I call insert_batch this way:

> return $this->db->insert_batch('tbl_quiz_answer', $data);

And the $data dump looks like this:

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id_quiz_master"]=>
    string(3) "500"
    ["id_quiz_question"]=>
    int(3248)
    ["id_student"]=>
    string(3) "305"
    ["answer"]=>
    string(3) "asd"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id_quiz_master"]=>
    string(3) "500"
    ["id_quiz_question"]=>
    int(3247)
    ["id_student"]=>
    string(3) "305"
    ["answer"]=>
    string(6) "asdasd"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id_quiz_master"]=>
    string(3) "500"
    ["id_quiz_question"]=>
    int(3246)
    ["id_student"]=>
    string(3) "305"
    ["answer"]=>
    string(3) "asd"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id_quiz_master"]=>
    string(3) "500"
    ["id_quiz_question"]=>
    int(3245)
    ["id_student"]=>
    string(3) "305"
    ["answer"]=>
    string(1) "b"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id_quiz_master"]=>
    string(3) "500"
    ["id_quiz_question"]=>
    int(3244)
    ["id_student"]=>
    string(3) "305"
    ["answer"]=>
    string(1) "b"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id_quiz_master"]=>
    string(3) "500"
    ["id_quiz_question"]=>
    int(3243)
    ["id_student"]=>
    string(3) "305"
    ["answer"]=>
    string(1) "d"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id_quiz_master"]=>
    string(3) "500"
    ["id_quiz_question"]=>
    int(3242)
    ["id_student"]=>
    string(3) "305"
    ["answer"]=>
    string(1) "a"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id_quiz_master"]=>
    string(3) "500"
    ["id_quiz_question"]=>
    int(3241)
    ["id_student"]=>
    string(3) "305"
    ["answer"]=>
    string(1) "a"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id_quiz_master"]=>
    string(3) "500"
    ["id_quiz_question"]=>
    int(3240)
    ["id_student"]=>
    string(3) "305"
    ["answer"]=>
    string(6) "asdasd"
  }
}
```

Help me please, I don't known what I did wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505594/php-codeigniter-batch-insert-not-accepting-my-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505594/php-codeigniter-batch-insert-not-accepting-my-array)

Comment: It's not the same because mine already has code, I assume '["id_quiz_master"]=>
  string(3) "500"' could be the code

Comment: And I already wrap my array inside an array

Comment: Any chance of seeing some of your code?

Comment: I'm sorry but that is as far as I can tell, basically from the value after var_dump($data) I can't tell what's wrong, I mean already wrapped and anything. But somehow it doesn't work

Comment: `Message: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given` is saying that what you are passing is not an array.  We need to see your code to be able to help.

Comment: I opened DB_active_rec.php and there's a variable named current($key) and I did var_dump on that, I feel weird when because current($key) is an array, which is like it supposed to be.

Comment: line 1109 -> $keys = array_keys(current($key)); is where the error occurs

Comment: `Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\squline_beta\dashboard\system\database\DB_active_rec.php` is not your problem, the information you are passing is the problem.  If you are not going to supply any code that YOU have created then no one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to build the array for insert_batch.  It may not be exactly like you need it but it will work and perform the insert without issue.

```
public function post_message( $post, $user_id )
{
    $message_data = array();

    foreach ($post[ 'to_id' ] as $key) {
        $message = array(
            'from_id'        => $user_id,
            'to_id'          => $key,
            'message'        => $post[ 'message' ],
            'sent_date_time' => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' )
            );
        $message_data[] = $message;
    }

    $this->db_central->insert_batch( 'messages', $message_data );

}
```